# Failure to add ODBC Data Connection for SQL

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I am trying to add a local SQL server as an ODBC data source for Crystal Reports, but I am unable to do so using the ODBC data source administrator. I have tried using both SQL and SQL Native Client drivers, but nothing is showing up in the selection drop-down. I have verified that I am using the correct 64-bit option by running `SELECT @@VERSION`. How can I proceed?

[image: nothing on odbc admin]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a local server on your machine, you can simply enter a dot (.) to indicate you wish to use the local server. What happens when you try that?